# Restricting the rotation of camera Scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

i am new to Scenekit but have got the basics down. I am attempting to restrict the rotation of the camera for the -y position if that makes sense. i have created a few cubes and would like to restrict the camera view to the sides and the top only.

i have tried constraining the the ground but that doesnt work, i have tried vector4 angles but doesnt seem to work. Apples documents dont seem to state much in terms of restricting movements outside of physics body. if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great. i have thought of trying y FOV next, for example

```
let camera = SCNCamera()

camera.yFov = 20
```

and somehow give a min and max range,

if any better ideas out there i would like to hear. thank you.